# Replicate this linux wget command with OSX's curl

Tags: macos, curl, wget

how can I replace this command with OSX's curl command?

`wget -O - http://download.freebase.com/datadumps/latest/freebase-simple-topic-dump.tsv.bz2 | bunzip2 | cut -f 2 > freebase-topic-names.txt`

I tried `curl "http://download.freebase.com/datadumps/latest/freebase-simple-topic-dump.tsv.bz2" -o | bunzip2 | cut -f 2 > freebase-topic-names.txt`

but that doesn't seem right and it is not working

Comment: Try installing `wget`. Install `homebrew` package manager for OSX then do `brew install wget`

Comment: @MarkSetchell can you post that as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider installing `wget` using `Homebrew`.

First, go to the `homebrew` website - [here](http://brew.sh) - and install it.

Then just do:

```
brew install wget
```

If you get any problems, just run:

```
brew doctor
```

If you want to find another package, just use:

```
brew search <package name or part of it>
```

If you want to update your installation, just do:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```